# Extraer valor numerico de un string con kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Como extraer de una cadena el valor hasta que encuentre un numero por ejemplo:

```
val cadena = "512ASND"
```

Quiero obtener el valor "512" de esa cadena!

Comment: Byron, acostumbra agregar lo que hayas tratado o investigado, esto te ayudará a tener excelentes respuestas ya que será atractivo a los desarrolladores mostrar lo que has tratado, mejora tus preguntas en base a lo que indica el documento [ask], saludos!.

Answer (score 1):

Con expresiones regulares puedes lograrlo, solo crea una expresion a partir de un string:

```
val regex = """[0-9]+""".toRegex()
```

después con el método find buscas la primer coincidencia.

```
val number = regex.find("512ASND")
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta Juan. Probe el codigo siguiente: 

val cadena = "512ASND"



val regex =  """[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]""".toRegex()


val numero = regex.find(cadena)



y el resultado que tengo es:


println("Numero: = {$regex}")


Numero: = {kotlin.text.MatcherMatchResult@3b81a1bc}


No se como interpretarlo, esperaria que me regresara el fragemento de la cadena de numeros o el de la posicion.

Comment: Lo siento el resultado de arriba es al imprimir la variable numero  
println(numero)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un método el cual revisa cada elemento de la cadena y obtiene únicamente los que son valores numéricos, este sería el método:

```
fun getNumericValues(cadena: String): String {

    val sb = StringBuilder()

    for (i in cadena.indices) {
        var numeric = true
        try {
            val num = parseDouble(cadena[i].toString())
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            numeric = false
        }

        if (numeric) {
            //es un valor numerico.
            sb.append(cadena[i].toString())
        } else {
            //no es valor numerico.
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

este es un ejemplo de uso:

```
val cadena = "512ASND"
println(getNumericValues(cadena));
```

para obtener como salida:

```
512
```

---

Realizando un poco de código obtuve este otro método el cual busca si cada elemento de la cadena es de tipo `String` entonces lo agrega a una `MutableList`

```
fun getNumericValues(cadena: String): String {

      val result : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>()
        var numberStr = ""
        for(i : Int in 0 until cadena.length){
            val c: Char = cadena[i]

            if(c in '0'..'9'){
                numberStr += c
                if(i == cadena.length - 1){
                    result.add(numberStr.toInt())
                }
            }else if(!numberStr.isNullOrBlank()){
                result.add(numberStr.toInt())
                numberStr = ""
            }

        }

        return result.joinToString(separator , "")
    }
```

este es un ejemplo de uso:

```
val cadena = "512ASND"
println(getNumericValues(cadena));
```

para obtener como salida:

```
512
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar el siguiente método que devuelve una lista de enteros que encuentra en la cadena que se le mande.

```
fun getNumbersFromInput(input: String): ArrayList<Int> {
val indexBlackList = arrayListOf<Int>()
val listOfNumbers = arrayListOf<Int>()
var number = 0
var lastIndex = 0
for (i in input.indices) {
    var isNumeric = true
    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(input[i].toString())
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        isNumeric = false
        indexBlackList.add(i)
    }
    if (isNumeric) {
        if (indexBlackList.contains(i - 1)) {
            if (listOfNumbers.size > 0) {
                lastIndex += 1
            }
            listOfNumbers.add(lastIndex, number)
        } else {
            if (listOfNumbers.size > 0) {
                val numberUpdate = listOfNumbers[lastIndex] * 10 + number
                listOfNumbers.removeAt(lastIndex)
                listOfNumbers.add(lastIndex, numberUpdate)
            } else {
                lastIndex = 0
                listOfNumbers.add(lastIndex, number)
            }
        }
    }
}
return listOfNumbers
```

}

Por ejemplo cuando se le manda:

```
"1583     //123.test 4 numeros15   3".
```

El método retorna:

```
[1583, 123, 4, 15, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Este codigo lo deduje de otro que vi en Kotlin.org:

```
   var cadena1 = "512ASDN" 
   var cadena2 = cadena1.filter{it in "0123456789"}
```

la cadena a filtrar (quitar lo que no sea numeros) se guarda en cadena1 y como el string tambien es una coleccion de caracteres, se puede utilizar el metodo "filter" de las colecciones, utilizando una lambda para manejar la busqueda de caracteres numericos en la cadena1.

El resultado filtrado queda guardado en cadena2, listo para ser impreso por consola o ser utilizado en otra expresion.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria la forma correcta.

```kotlin
val regex = """[0-9]+""".toRegex()

val number = regex.find("512ASND")?.value ?: ""

print(number)

Resultado: 512
```

Credito a Juan M. Carballo, ya que fue su respuesta, solo que lo modifique.